# Parsing JSON result to object by using checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, checkbox

I have loaded a JSON list into a table and I would like to parse 1 JSON result or multiple results into an object, so I can send it to the server.

My table looks like this so far:

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in student">
    <td ng-model="herkanserNaam">{{ t.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ t.City }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="checkbox" ng-click="laatzien(herkanserNaam, herkanserCheck)" ng-model="herkanserCheck">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox">
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Controller

```
$scope.laatzien = function(name, active) {  

    var herkanser = [{
    "name" :  name,
    "active" : false
    }];
    console.log(herkanser);

}
```

How would I be able to check one or multiple results and save the data(t.Name) into an object by using a checkbox? So far the function laatzien() is returning the empty values defined in herkanser.

Comment: I don't think a `td` can have an `ngModel`.... Pass in `t.name` to your function and remove that `ngModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `laatzien` method is failing is due to how you are using your directives. Let's work with the example you provided to get your `laatzien` method to fire.

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in students">
    <td>{{ student.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.City }}</td>
    <td>van</td>
    <td>Huis</td>
    <td>j.huis@student.han.nl</td>
    <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.isActive" ng-change="laatzien(student)">
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.laatzien = function (student) {
    var herkanser = [{
        "name": student.name,
        "active": student.isActive
    }];
    console.log(herkanser);
}
```

I have made some opinionated changes in your example for readability purposes, others were needed to get the directives to fire as expected. Below are the changes to your snippets.

1. Renamed the `student` array to `students`. This will require a change in your controller from `$scope.student` to `$scope.students`.
2. Renamed the `t` object to `student`.
3. Removed the `ng-click` directive from your div.
4. Added an `ng-change` directive on your checkbox. Now when you click the checkbox your `laatzien` method should fire.
5. Added an `isActive` property to your `student`. Inside of your `laatzien` method, you may now check the state of the checkbox. If the checkbox is checked, `student.isActive = true`. If the checkbox is not checked, `student.isActive = false`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function to push thet item into an obj like so...

```
$scope.students = [
    {
        "name":"John",
        "city":"Boston"
    },
    {
        "name":"Amy",
        "city":"Dallas"
    }
    ]

$scope.activeObj = [];

$scope.laatzien = function(obj) {  
    if($.inArray(obj, $scope.activeObj) == -1) {
        $scope.activeObj.push(obj); 
    } else {
        var index = $scope.activeObj.indexOf(obj);
        $scope.activeObj.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5fcnazb2/

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you seem to want to build the "list of checked students" and send that to the server. In other words, what you want, is to allow the user to check on multiple students and at the end collect everything that was checked and send it over to the server.

If that's the case then your strategy to put an ng-click over the checkbox is wrong.

What you need is to bind your checkbox to your $scope model. Such as this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="t.isChecked" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false'">
```

When the user checks the checkbox for a student. Your model will automatically be updated.

To collect the data to send over the server you need to put an ng-click on a submit button. In the event handler, simply loop through every student in your $scope "students" model and only save the ones that have isChecked property to true to be sent over to the server.

Hope this helps!